# java permissions in libraries

Tags: java, security, maven, jna

I have a program that uses the JNA library (managed with maven). The program itself has all permissions (I got a `FilePermission` error, changed the policy file, and now I can read/write at will). However, when I use JNA, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission jna.encoding read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:393)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:669)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:682)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:598)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:356)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:276)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:216)
```

My policy file is (that last grant obvioulsy doesn't work):

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/tm/workspace/-" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
grant codeBase "file:/home/tm/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/-" {
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "jna.encoding", "read";
};
```

I'm running the program in eclipse, from a project in the workspace directory. Any ideas which permissions I need to assign to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `RMISecurityManager`s in place since it was a distributed program. When I removed all calls to `setSecurityManager`, the problem stopped. I presume `System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());` doesn't pick up the policy file.